# totaljs websocket module vs socket.io

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket, socket.io, total.js

I'm using total.js to create a website and I'm quiet a newbie using it, this might be a newbie question as well, does total.js wbesocket module works the same as socket.io? Does it have a fallback mechanism such as socket.io? if not is it possible to use socket.io with total.js? I'm quiet lost here and my search has ended up useless.

any help or hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/totaljs/websocket/totaljs/KYLih2aSNEY/THaAh9G5JXEJ), you can freely use socket.io with total.js, however you can also use the total.js default websockets with an XHR alternative.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer (link), so basically totaljs default websockets doesn't have the fallback functionality same as socket.io and I have to do the fallback implementation by myself, am I right?

Comment: I've got my answer within the link inside the link you've posted :) thanks again.